# Rails 4 scopes: grab all records between opposite scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
#models/foobar.rb
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::base
  scope :active, ->{where(active: true)}
  scope :inactive, ->{where(active: false)}
end
```

What I want to do is get an activerecord relation object that contains all the `foobar` records that are active.  Then: I also want this same activerecord relation object to contain all `foobar` records that are inactive.

I don't think this does what I want it to:

```
# only returns the active records
Foobar.active.inactive
```

This wouldn't work either because it returns an array, not an activerecord relation object:

```
# returns an array not an activerecord relation object
Foobar.active + Foobar.inactive
```

How can I get the activerecord relation object to contain BOTH active and inactive foobar records? Better yet: Is there a way to create a scope that would do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
scope :active_and_inactive, ->{where(active: [true,false])}
```

Through using Array you can pass multiple values for an attribute.

Comment: I used status instead of a boolean for active and the scope looks like this:
`scope :active, -> { where(status: "Active") }`